# ¿cómo autoajustar un panel al tamaño vertical del no. de componentes en el IDE de netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-netbeans

Estoy haciendo en una ventana (en el IDE 17 de apache netbeans) una lista en un panel (JPanel) con varios checkbox (JCheckBox), pero la ventana es más pequeña que el contenido del panel y obviamente automáticamente se va a poner un scroll bar.

[image: lista de JCheckbox en JPanel]

¿Me gustaría conocer como se puede modificar el scrollbar para que este llegue solo a indicar el último elemento de la lista de checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione modificando los valores de las propiedades `minimunSize` y `preferredSize` para que sean iguales y no dar posibilidad a que se modifique